# Restrict Item by Base Template on a Field IncludeTemplatesForSelection

Tags: content-editor, information-architecture, templates

Out of the box it is possible to restrict items in a fields data source by its base template type. I can specify a filter as follows that restricts to items of type `Employee`...

```
DataSource=/sitecore/content/home/people/employees&IncludeTemplatesForSelection=Employee
```

If `Employee` uses `Person` as its base template, I'd like to specify something like this...

```
DataSource=/sitecore/content/home/people&IncludeBaseTemplatesForSelection=Person
```

That would allow me to select any item that has `Person` as its base template (so allow I could select `Person` and `Employee` items, or any other item that derives from `Person` base template.).

Is this possible?

Comment: I do not believe this is possible out of the box. You would need a custom solution for it

Comment: More than happy to write a custom solution. I was thinking I might have to plug something somewhere into the pipeline. I've already have a thorough poke around without much luck though. I wonder if anyone's already done something custom around this already that's in the public domain?

Comment: @PhilHarvey Are you wanting to make this change for the "Datasource Location" field on renderings or the "Source" of template fields (e.g., Droptree, Treelist, Multilist)?

Comment: @CoreySmith i'd like to do this on the "Source" of template fields. It would be nice of I could do it on Datasource Location too, but my requirement is to have this on fields.

Comment: @JammyKam and I have both blogged on extending the Treelist field Source. You might find these helpful in your custom solution.
- JammyKam's post: https://jammykam.wordpress.com/2016/01/06/specifying-query-and-parameters-for-sitecore-treelist-field-source/
- My post: http://blogs.perficient.com/microsoft/2016/05/sitecore-extend-treelist-to-support-relative-datasource-paths/

Comment: @JammyKam thanks! this is great, I can see how I could extend the TreeList control then expand some parameters. E.g. if I had the following datasource set on a field...

`DataSource=/sitecore/content/home/people&IncludeTemplatesForSelection=@Person`

...replace @Person with a comma separated list of all the templates that derive from it. My only concern is how poorly this might perform. It would translate the above parameter into this...

`DataSource=/sitecore/content/home/people&IncludeTemplatesForSelection=Person,Employee`

Answer (score 1):

I've had to do something similar recently which involved extending the treeview and used JammyKams post as a guide so thought I'd have a go at putting something together for this:

```
public class TreelistWithChildTemplateSupport : TreeList
{

    [Description("Base templates to include.")]
    [Category("Data")]
    public string IncludeBaseTemplatesForSelection
    {
        get { return GetViewStateString("IncludeBaseTemplatesForSelection"); }
        set
        {
            Assert.ArgumentNotNull(value, "value");
            SetViewStateString("IncludeBaseTemplatesForSelection", value);
        }
    }

    public new virtual void Add()
    {
    if (!this.HasIncludeBaseTemplatesForSelection(selectionItem))
      return;
    base.Add();
   }

  private bool HasIncludeBaseTemplatesForSelection(Item item)
  {
  Assert.ArgumentNotNull((object) item, "item");
  if (this.IncludeBaseTemplatesForSelection.Length == 0)
    return true;
  return HasItemBaseTemplate(item, this.IncludeBaseTemplatesForSelection);
 }
}
```

Then in the HasItemBaseTemplate() you could do something similar to Anders post here: https://laubplusco.net/sitecore-extensions-does-a-sitecore-item-derive-from-a-template/

I've not tested this code but hopefully this is a good start for you.